# Trouble Updating Label Text

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

Environment:

- Built interface using Glade3.
- Backend is written in Python using the GTK+ Builder library.

-

Although I know the method I need to use to update a label's text (label.set_text("string")), I'm having trouble obtaining the label object in the python code.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: HelloPython.py
# Author: Andrew Hefley Carpenter
# Date: 18 August 2010

import sys
import gtk

class HelloPython:

    def on_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("HelloPython.xml") 

        self.window = builder.get_object("window")
        builder.connect_signals(self)   

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):

        print "Hello World!"  
        widget.set_label("Hello World!")
        #I'd like to update 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    editor = HelloPython()
    editor.window.show()
    gtk.main()
```

End goal: I want to update "Object X" using it's set_text method after the callback to "Object Y" (in this case button1) as handled by "on_button1_clicked"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget parameter to on_button1_clicked is a gtk.Button, not a gtk.Label. gtk.Button has a convenience api method called set_label().

This only works if the child of Gtk.Button is a gtk.Label. This is the default when creating a new button in Glade-3, but if you've changed the contents of the button, this will not work and you'll need a reference to the gtk.Label widget itself.

EDIT (code to update the label):

```
class HelloPython:
    def on_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("HelloPython.xml") 
        self.window = builder.get_object("window")
        self.label = builder.get_object("label1") # get reference to the label
        builder.connect_signals(self)   

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        #widget.set_label("Hello World!") this would set the button's text
        self.label.set_text("Hello World!") # this sets the label's text
```

Comment: Understandable. The container hierarchy is as follows:

-Window has one child, vertical box '2 containers'
-vertical box has two children, button1 and label1. 
-I'd like to have label1 update when it's sibling, button1 is clicked. How can I achieve this/what conceptual barriers are preventing me from figuring this out?

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: ah, gtk doesn't know or care about this "sibling" relationship. you'll need to get a reference to the label using gtk.Builder.get_object() and call set_text on that object.

Comment: also, you'll want to get out of the habit of using glade's default widget names (button1, label1) as soon as possible, otherwise your life will suck.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the very beginning of a project that will  help the bioinformatics community by visualizing splice junctions.